# How to resolve npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree - simple react lightbox?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to resolve an error with my Gatsby project.

I got the following error when I run npm update in my CLI:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from simple-react-lightbox@3.6.9-0
npm ERR! node_modules/simple-react-lightbox
npm ERR!   simple-react-lightbox@"^3.6.9-0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

When I build (gatsby build) the website via the CLI it works, but when I deploy it to Netlify I get the same error:

```
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! While resolving: simple-react-lightbox@3.6.9-0
4:05:39 PM: Creating deploy upload records
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8 || ^17.0.0" from framer-motion@4.1.17
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/framer-motion
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!     framer-motion@"^4.1.17" from simple-react-lightbox@3.6.9-0
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/simple-react-lightbox
4:05:40 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!       simple-react-lightbox@"^3.6.9-0" from the root project
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!   15 more (nano-css, react-dom, react-helmet, react-masonry-css, ...)
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from simple-react-lightbox@3.6.9-0
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/simple-react-lightbox
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!   simple-react-lightbox@"^3.6.9-0" from the root project
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2" from simple-react-lightbox@3.6.9-0
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/simple-react-lightbox
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!     simple-react-lightbox@"^3.6.9-0" from the root project
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR!
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
4:05:39 PM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the package has been deprecated. It's no longer been supported since a short time ago. I've downgraded react from 18 to 17. That seems to work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-lightbox

**My steps:**

1. downgraded react 18 to 17
   `(npm install --save react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2)`
2. Deleted Gatsby cache
   `gatsby clean`
3. Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json
4. Reinstalled npm
   `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem some minutes ago, but I was able to solve it by forcefully installing it using the `--force` flag, so you'd install it by:

```
npm install --force simple-react-lightbox
```

What I believe the problem is, is that the dependency/package you want to install is built upon react v17.x and you're working with a project on react v18.x

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hey Dev Emmy, thanks for your message! Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Basically crashed the app, can't run development or build right now. If you have other suggestions, please let me know! :)